# Teradata column not sorting correctly

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to join two tables by a column, and sort a table by the same column.

Here is some example data from the two tables:

**table.x**

```
state
00039
01156
```

**table.y**

```
state
39
1156
```

How do I join and sort the tables in SQL assistant?

Comment: What data type is `y.state`?

Comment: @KamilG's reply below will help you with the join.  For sorting, the data type is critical. Character/varchar and numeric data types do not sort the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to cast both sides to `integer` as @Andrew mentioned, so you could use simple casting, or `trycast(...)` which will try to cast the value and if that fails won't return an error, but `NULL` value instead:

```
select *
from x
inner join y on
  trycast(y.state as integer) = trycast(y.state as integer)
order by y.state
```

---

**Old answer** (leaving this here for sake of future readers and what you can / can't do):

If you have a recent version of Teradata (you didn't specify it) you would also have `LPAD` function. Assuming that `y.state` is not text, but a number we'd also need to cast it, as lpad takes string as argument. If it is, omit `cast(...)`:

```
select *
from x
inner join y on
  x.state = lpad(cast(y.state as varchar(5)), 5, '0')
order by y.state
```

If you don't have an `LPAD` function, then some dirty code with `substring` might come in handy:

```
select *
from x
inner join y on
  x.state = substring('00000' from char_length(cast(y.state as varchar(5))+1) || cast(y.state as varchar(5)
order by y.state
```

Above assumes that you store numbers within maximum 5 digits. If it's beyond that number (your sample data says 5) then you need to adjust the code.

Comment: While we're throwing out dirty solutions, you can just cast the columns as integer on both sides, which basically strips off the leading 0s.

Comment: @Andrew totally fair point, yes, somehow I've overthought this.

Comment: Instead of adding leading zeroes you can also trim leading zeroes: `trim(leading '0' from state)` :-)